# DRF: Need Guidance to perform a task

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rest

I need to create an API to book a call with an advisor

Endpoint: /user/<user_id>/advisor/<advisor_id>/

for this used `path('user/<int:user_id>/advisor/<int:advisor_id>')` in urls.py

but the problem is I have to request a ***Booking time(a DateTime sting)*** when I make a request to that link which I can perform via PostMan

In ***serilaizer.py*** I used:

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Booking
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = models.Booking.objects.create(
            user=validated_data['user'], advisor=validated_data['advisor'], time=validated_data['time'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

***views.py***

```
class BookAdvisorAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializer.BookingSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = models.Booking.objects.all()
```

In this i have pass everything via the body in postman but I want to use the `user_id` and `advisor_id` from the url and just want to provide DateTime string via body in PostMan

Comment: can you add the view?

Comment: added views.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this should work,

```
class BookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Booking
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ("user", "advisor")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        view_kwargs = self.context["view"].kwargs
        booking = models.Booking.objects.create(
            user_id=view_kwargs["user_id"],
            advisor_id=view_kwargs["advisor_id"],
            time=validated_data['time']
        )
        return booking
```

Comment: I tried this but it is still asking for user and advisor in response

Comment: You need to set the `read_only_fields` in the serializer. See the update